# How to let pyInstaller find datafiles when your package is imported by others

Tags: python, pyinstaller, setuptools

As a user of the [`iapws`](https://iapws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package, I got hit by a general issue that I don't manage to solve.
The package is small, and a good candidate look at.

A simples script is the following (I called it `main.py`):

```
from iapws import IAPWS97

def main():
    h = IAPWS97(P=1, x=1).h
    print(f"h = {h:.5g} kJ/kg")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This script works fine. Packaging this via `pyinstaller main.py` creates the `dist\main` folder with `main.exe` inside.
Executing `main.exe` yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "iapws\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\...\\dist\\main\\iapws\\VERSION'
[22492] Failed to execute script main
```

The issue here is the missing `VERSION` file, i.e. a data file of the `iapws` package, which I as the packager of my importing package should not have to bother about. I cloned the `iapws` package and tried to specify the `VERSION` data file in the `setup.py` in several ways, but `pyInstaller` doesn't pick it up.

**What can how be specified inside the `iapws` package to trigger `pyInstaller` to pick such datafiles up?**

This issue is communicated with the `iapws` developer(s) [here](https://github.com/jjgomera/iapws/issues/52).

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, `pyInstaller` allows hooks to be applied. In this case, create a hook called `hook-iapws.py` with the content

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('iapws')
```

As a **user** of the package, the hook is found by pointing on the containing directory in the pyinstaller specfile:

```
a = Analysis(...
             hookspath=["pyinstaller-hooks"],
             ...)
```

As a **developer** of the package, the hook can be made found by `pyInstaller` as described [in this link](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#provide-hooks-with-package) or by providing the hook-file to the pyInstaller developers.

Answer (score 0):

I answered on another thread, but same applies here:

You need to force pyinstaller to include iapws files, as it seems to have issues generating the appropriate hooks. This worked for me:

```
pyinstaller "your_script.py" --collect-all iapws
```

I reviewed command options here which helped: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html